# how to refresh the current window using c# in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
if (TextBox1.Text == row["UserName"].ToString() 
    && TextBox2.Text == row["Password"].ToString())
{   
    //here i have to reload the page
    Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('Login SucessFull')");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is more what you want? It will show an alert and then redirect you to another page.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "LoggedInScript", "alert('Login SucessFull'); window.location = 'MyLoggedInPage.aspx';", true);
```

Comment: : hi thanks pa its working bot i need without pressing ok button in alert window i have to get the backside page i.e., main page then when i press ok button in alert it should allow us to enter the username and all

Answer (score 0):

When you say you need to "reload the page" do you mean redirect to another page becuase the user is now logged in?  If you you use:

```
Response.Redirect("MyLoggedInPage.aspx")
```

Comment: k thanks i got it but for first click its not giving the alert for 2nd click it show the alert box i have to get the alert in first click only what can i doo?